# PHPMailer or wp_mail integration to Plugin - Or Alternative? Contact Submit to send two seperate emails with attachments

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, phpmailer

I have tried for days to merge a piece of PHPMailer code that works great into a WordPress plugin with zero success. I am happy to go down another route as long as it achieves the goal of sending two separate emails via one contact form submit: 1, to the email address entered into the contact for with a fixed message, subject and an attachment; 2, containing the message entered into the form to the fixed email address.

Your input to help me crack this would be hugely appreciated.

Please find attached a JSFiddle. Of course, this is PHP code and will not function but I felt it was far better than to paste reams of code here.

The existing working Mailer code works great and actioned everything I wanted to achieve (described above). Please see below the working PHPMailer code that I wish to integrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/CUMzq/

```
<?php

      $field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury']; // cf_name is a convention used by the HTML form
      $field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
      $field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    // E-Mail to Client

    $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

    $body = "Hello $field_fullname,<br><br>\r\nThank you for contacting the BUSINESS. We will endeavour to contact you as soon as possible. In the meantime, we have attached a PDF booklet which will provide you with more information.<br><br>\r\nKind regards<br><br>\r\nBUSINESS";

    $mail->SetFrom('example@email.co.uk', 'BUSINESS'); 

    $mail->AddReplyTo('example@email.co.uk', 'BUSINESS');

    $address = $field_email;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $field_fullname);

    $mail->Subject    = 'Auto-Response: Thank you for contacting the BUSINESS, '.$field_fullname;

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAttachment("/url/path/to/demo/business/booklet.pdf");      // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

    $sent = $mail->Send();


    // E-Mail to Company

    $mail2 = clone $mail;

    $mail2             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

    $body = $field_message;

    $mail2->SetFrom($field_email, $field_fullname); 

    $mail2->AddReplyTo($field_email, $field_fullname);

    $address = "example@email.co.uk";
    $mail2->AddAddress($address, "BUSINESS");

    $mail2->Subject    = 'Enquiry via the ETAP Centre website from '.$field_fullname;

    $mail2->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail2->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail2->AddAttachment(""); // attachment - leave incase they are needed in the future
    $mail2->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

    $sent = $mail2->Send();

    if($sent) {
      { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for contacting the BUSINESS. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    }
    } else {
      ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send your email to example@email.co.uk');
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Any and all help would be hugely appreciated and if I can do anything more to articulate my question and/or increase its understandability just let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)?

Comment: @Bart unfortunately, I do not know enough about the subject to answer that. I simply found PHPMailer template and edited it because I was advised on StackOverflow to use that as it was easier to send attachments. I am happy to persue any path as long as it allows me to send two emails to different addresses: one with the message and the second a fixed message and an attachment. Would you recommend wp_mail?

Comment: I think you missed the link on `wp_mail` in my previous comment :-) Yes I would recommend it. It's much simpler to use. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail. You should always research the possibilities of your current platform before dragging in third parties.

Comment: Oh right thanks. Will this still work with the plugin? Would I just replace the plugin code or?

Comment: You can make it work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_mail to send mail attachments-

```
<?php
  $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');
  $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
  wp_mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments);
?>
```

For sending HTML content use this:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); // reset content-type    to to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
function set_html_content_type()
{
return 'text/html';
}
?>
```

For more information refer to this link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: so I just match up the markup and then copy of the relevant plugin code?

Comment: yes you can add this code where you submit contact code and be sure to add "wp_mail_content_type" filter if you sending html content as mention above.